# Duplicating a list based on elements in its list of lists

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have the following list:

```
a = [1, 2, ['c', 'd'], 3, 4, ['e', 'f'], 5, 6]
```

The number of list of lists in `a` can vary, but the no. of elements in each list of lists will remain same.

for example, like below:

```
a = [1, 2, ['c', 'd'], 3, 4, ['e', 'f'], 5, 6, ['g', 'h'], 7, 8]
```

or

```
a = [1, 2, ['c', 'd', 'e'], 3, 4, ['f', 'g', 'h'], 5, 6, ['i', 'j', 'k'], 7, 8]
```

so for the **input:**

```
a = [1, 2, ['c', 'd'], 3, 4, ['e', 'f'], 5, 6]
```

I'm expecting the below **output:**

```
[[1, 2, 'c', 3, 4, 'e', 5, 6], [1, 2, 'd', 3, 4, 'f', 5, 6]]
```

Based on the no. of list of lists, the lists should be duplicated as shown in the above format.

And for the below input:

```
a = [1, 2, ['c', 'd', 'e'], 3, 4, ['f', 'g', 'h'], 5, 6, ['i', 'j', 'k'], 7, 8]
```

The output should be:

```
[[1, 2, 'c', 3, 4, 'f', 5, 6, 'i', 7, 8],
 [1, 2, 'd', 3, 4, 'g', 5, 6, 'j', 7, 8],
 [1, 2, 'e', 3, 4, 'h', 5, 6, 'k', 7, 8]]
```

So far, I'm able to do the following thing:

```
a = [1,2,['c','d'],3,4]

for i in a:
    if type(i) == list:
        t = a.index(i)
        ind = a[t]
        #idx.append(ind)
        a.remove(i)


new = []

for i in ind:
    new1 = []
    for j in a:
        new1.append(j)
    new1.insert(t,i)
    new.append(new1)

new

>> [[1, 2, 'c', 3, 4], [1, 2, 'd', 3, 4]]
```

How to expand the code I wrote to achieve the required task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given input list, collect:

- the indices of the sublists
- the sublists themselves

then use `zip()` to create an iterable over the *columns* of the sublists (combining all the 1st elements, then all the 2nd elements, etc.). Insert those column values into a copy of the original list at the collected indices:

```
def expand_lists(a):
    indices = []
    sublists = []
    for idx, elem in enumerate(a):
        if isinstance(elem, list):
            indices.append(idx)
            sublists.append(elem)

    results = []
    for combo in zip(*sublists):
        result = a[:]  # shallow copy, because sublists are replaced
        for idx, value in zip(indices, combo):
            result[idx] = value
        results.append(result)

    return results
```

Demo:

```
>>> expand_lists([1, 2, ['c', 'd'], 3, 4, ['e', 'f'], 5, 6])
[[1, 2, 'c', 3, 4, 'e', 5, 6], [1, 2, 'd', 3, 4, 'f', 5, 6]]
>>> expand_lists([1, 2, ['c', 'd', 'e'], 3, 4, ['f', 'g', 'h'], 5, 6, ['i', 'j', 'k'], 7, 8])
[[1, 2, 'c', 3, 4, 'f', 5, 6, 'i', 7, 8], [1, 2, 'd', 3, 4, 'g', 5, 6, 'j', 7, 8], [1, 2, 'e', 3, 4, 'h', 5, 6, 'k', 7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 7):

The issue with your code is that `t` is a single index, you must make it a `list` of indices to account for multiple sublists.

Although, let me suggest alternatives...

## With generators

We can transform the non-list elements to repeated generators and then use `zip`. This takes advantage of the fact that `zip` will stop iteration whenever it exhausted one of its arguments.

```
from itertools import repeat

def expand_list(lst):
    if not any(isinstance(el, list) for el in lst):
        return []
    else:
        return list(zip(*[x if isinstance(x, list) else repeat(x) for x in lst]))
```

The if-statement treats the base case when no item in your list is itself a list. An empty list is then returned. Alternatively, you could also define this case as returning only the list itself.

Example:

```
a = [1, 2, ['c', 'd', 'e'], 3, 4, ['f', 'g', 'h'], 5, 6, ['i', 'j', 'k'], 7, 8]
expand_list(a)
# output:
# [(1, 2, 'c', 3, 4, 'f', 5, 6, 'i', 7, 8),
#  (1, 2, 'd', 3, 4, 'g', 5, 6, 'j', 7, 8),
#  (1, 2, 'e', 3, 4, 'h', 5, 6, 'k', 7, 8)]
```

## With exceptions

If you are not that into generators, the following solution uses `list.pop` to pick the next item when it encounters a list until the sublists are empty. An `IndexError` will indicate that we exhausted our sublists.

```
import copy

def expand_list(lst):
    if not any(isinstance(el, list) for el in lst):
        return []

    lst = copy.deepcopy(lst)
    output = []

    while True:
        try:
            output.append([x.pop(0) if isinstance(x, list) else x for x in lst])
        except IndexError:
            # Sublists are now empty
            break

    return output
```